# Pandas dataframe filter out rows with non-english text

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, nlp, nltk

I have a pandas `df` which has 6 columns, the last one is `input_text`. I want to remove from `df` all rows that have non-english text in that column. I would like to use `langdetect`'s `detect` function.

Some template

```
from langdetect import detect
import pandas as pd

def filter_nonenglish(df):
    new_df = None  # Do some magical operations here to create the filtered df
    return new_df

df = pd.read_csv('somecsv.csv')
df_new = filter_nonenglish(df)
print('New df is: ', df_new)
```

Note! It doesn't matter what the other 5 columns are.
Also note: using `detect` is as simple as:

```
t = 'I am very cool!'
print(detect(t))
```

Output is:

```
en
```

Comment: It turned out that langdetect is slow on large documents, so any method will be fine!

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: "I want to remove from df all rows that have non-english text in that column. I would like to use langdetect's detect function."

Comment: As I pointed out, the values in the dataframe are irrelevant. The problem can be solved solely by using the last input_column, which is a string, as I have specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as below on your `df` and get all the rows with english text in the `input_text` column:

```
df_new = df[df.input_text.apply(detect).eq('en')]
```

So basically just apply the `langdetect.detect` function to the values in `input_text` column and get all those rows for which text is detected as **"en"**.

Comment: when 'input_text' null then how to handle ? can advise on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73087862/langdetect-error-keyerror-comment-when-null-key