# How to check which row in producing LangDetectException error in LangDetect?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, twitter

I have a dataset of tweets that contains tweets mainly from English but also have several tweets in Indian Languages (such as Punjabi, Hindi, Tamil etc.). I want to keep only English language tweets and remove rows with different language tweets.
I tried this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67786493/pandas-dataframe-filter-out-rows-with-non-english-text] and it worked on the sample dataset. However, when I tried it on my dataset it showed error:

`LangDetectException: No features in text.`

Also, I have already checked other question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69804094/drop-non-english-rows-pandasand] where the accepted answer talks about this error and mentioned that empty rows might be the reason for this error, so I already cleaned my dataset to remove all the empty rows.

Simple code which worked on sample data but not on original data:

```
from langdetect import detect
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Sample.csv')
df_new = df[df.text.apply(detect).eq('en')]
print('New df is: ', df_new)
```

How can I check which row is producing error?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function for return `True` if function `detect` failed:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Sample.csv')

def f(x):
    try:
        detect(x)
        return False
    except:
        return True

s = df.loc[df.text.apply(f), 'text']
```

Another idea is create new column filled by `detect`, if failed return `NaN`, last filtr rows with missing values to `df1` and also `df_new` with new column filled by ouput of function `detect`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Sample.csv')

def f1(x):
    try:
        return detect(x)
    except:
        return np.nan

df['new'] = df.text.apply(f1)

df1 = df[df.new.isna()]

df_new = df[df.new.eq('en')]
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where should I place the above custom function in my code?Also, do I have to change in 'x' with 'text'. I am just the beginner.

Comment: It is showing the same error : LangDetectException: No features in text. And another error also showing: NameError: name 'LangDetectException' is not defined

Comment: @PiyushGhasiya - do you think my code raise error? Or code `df_new = df[df.text.apply(detect).eq('en')]` ?

Comment: The earlier code with LangDetectException raised the error. Now (after the edits), the present code I am running, it is still haven't finished running yet. Once it will stop I can tell you about whether the present code is running smoothly or not.

Comment: @PiyushGhasiya - It is some large DataFrame?

Comment: @PiyushGhasiya - added another solution for run function only once - is returned `NaN` if exception

Comment: Thank you for all the help. My dataset is very large (millions rows) and it has been running since 2 hours. Is it usual or there is something wrong? Should I interrupt and run again with the second solution?

Comment: It worked. Apparently as the dataset was huge it took several hours but finally it worked. I can't thank you enough.