# langdetect error KeyError: 'comment' when null key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to Python and Panda Dataframe, I tried to read facebook page posts and its comments,

supposed to get this kind of result with the following cell

[image]

```
from langdetect import detect

def detect_en(text):
    try:
        return detect(text) == 'en'
    except:
        return False

df_comments = df_comments[df_comments['comment'].apply(detect_en)]

df_comments
```

I'm getting the following error

> KeyError: 'comment'
> [image]

but it seems fails with `df_comments['comment']` null occations,

Comment: Its a key error, so it thinks you are trying to pull 'comment' from df_comments hash?? Are you trying to store the comments into df_comments? I'm not sure whats going on?

Comment: @AaronCloud try to filter to take English comments only,

Comment: This isn't english?

Comment: @AaronCloud asks, to check `df_comments` data(Value). Does your `df_comments` has "comment" column in it?

Comment: @AaronCloud yes its mixture of other language, here I try to filterout

Comment: @Xitiz yes it has  'comment' column

Answer (score 0):

There might be some whitespaces in the columns which cannot be seen from the output of `DataFrame`. You can check it by printing the column names `print(df.columns)` or just rename the column names directly

```
df.columns = ['post_id', 'comment', 'sentiment']
```